# Need help identifying cipher (hash type?)

Tags: hash

This is it: c6dd657d235344b4fcbf5ba88a47550d6992d16e

It probably contains coordinates. Not sure tho.

Answer (score 2):

Learn to use Google.
Google the Hash at first, small result it'll show up but you never know.

As second, there are tons of Hash-identifiers, the best and most used one names Hash-ID. It's a tool.

Quick alternatives are online as well:
http://www.onlinehashcrack.com/hash-identification.php

It's probably SHA-1.